# is 'how-being' correct or acceptable?

Tags: meaning

I heard "how-being" on international media and was wondering if it is correct.

> I asked about his health and **how-being**.

Comment: Any context to this quote?

Comment: I don't know, it was said in a report in France 24, I believe.

Comment: The term is "well-being".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a play-on of [well-being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-being). I have never heard of "how-being", and I'm sure I'm not the only one. According to an [Ngram of "well-being, how-being"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=well-being%2Chow-being&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwell%20-%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20-%20being%3B%2Cc0), the latter is most likely something made up.

My best guess is that the speaker meant well-being, or something close to "... his health and state of happiness."

Comment: @mahpack Actually it would be closest to asking, "I ask about his health and state of happiness." (perhaps also "state of health", but I assume "happiness" since "health" would be redundant)

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect. The phrase is ***well-being***.

The fact that you saw/heard it on an international site may indicate it was written/said by a non-native speaker.

Comment: Well-being means healthy or in good shape, doesn't mean 'health'. I am certain he said 'how-being', I personally have never heard of it, was just curious. From the context, it alludes to health.

Comment: I didn't claim that 'well-being' means 'health'. It would be superfluous to say, 'I asked about his health and health'.   He may have said 'how-being' - but was he a native English speaker? If not, it was a mistake. If so it was a joke or a neologism.